# How to change a value in a certain postion of the matrix(and return the whole matrix changed)?

Tags: haskell

My current code is below. I think all of the functions, except for the last one are correct. What I'm trying to achieve with `changeValueMatrix` is to give a matrix, a matrix position and a value and then that value will replace the one that is at the current position. I've managed to reach the position and to change the value but I can only return the row on which I changed it and not the whole matrix. I am a Haskell beginner and I've only learned recursion just now but it would be ideal to use it here if possible.

```
type Matrix a = [[a]]
type MatrixDimension = (Int,Int)  
type MatrixPosition = (Int,Int)

matrixDimension :: Matrix a -> MatrixDimension
matrixDimension m = (length m, length (head m))

returnValueList :: Int -> [a] -> a
returnValueList 0 (x:xs) = x
returnValueList i(x:xs) = returnValue (i-1)(xs)

changeValueList :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
changeValueList 0 value (x:xs) = (value:xs)
changeValueList i value (x:xs) =  x:(changeValueList (i-1) (value) (xs))

returnValueMatrix :: MatrixPosition-> Matrix a -> a
returnValueMatrix(m,n) matrix = returnValueList n (returnreturnValueList matrix) 

changeValueMatrix :: MatrixPosition -> a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
changeValueMatrix(0,c) value (x:xs) = a:xs          
              where a = changeValueList c value x

changeValueMatrix(r,c) valor (x:xs) = 
              where 
                    row = returnValueList r (x:xs)
                    b = changeValueList c value row
```

Comment: I presume `returnValue` in `returnValueList` ought to read `returnValueList`, and `returnreturnValueList matrix` should be `returnValueList m matrix`

Answer (score 0):

You can build `changeValueMatrix` from the functions you’ve already defined:

```
changeValueMatrix :: MatrixPosition -> a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
changeValueMatrix (r, c) value matrix
  = changeValueList r              -- (3)
    (changeValueList c value       -- (2)
      (returnValueList r matrix))  -- (1)
    matrix
```

At (1) you look up the row at index `r` in `matrix`, at (2) you replace the element at column `c` in that row with `value`, and at (3) you replace the row at index `r` in `matrix` with the modified row. For example:

```
-- Given: mat = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

changeValueMatrix (1, 1) 0 mat
==
changeValueList 1
  (changeValueList 1 0
    (returnValueList 1 mat))
  mat
==
changeValueList 1
  (changeValueList 1 0 [4, 5, 6])
  mat
==
changeValueList 1 [4, 0, 6] mat
==
[ [1, 2, 3]
, [4, 0, 6]
, [7, 8, 9]
]
```

If you want a version of this using explicit recursion, which only traverses the rows once, you can inline the definition of `changeValueList` into `changeValueMatrix`:

```
changeValueMatrix (0, c) value (x : xs)
  = changeValueList c value x : xs

changeValueMatrix (r, c) value (x : xs)
  = x : changeValueMatrix (r - 1, c) value xs
```

Be aware that your code has a few failure cases, though:

- Negative indices will produce infinite loops because you only test for `0` and recur with `i - 1` on any other number
- Overly large indices will run into the end of the list and crash because you don’t handle the `[]` case—the pattern matches are non-exhaustive, which the compiler will point out when enabling all warnings with `-Wall`
- Similarly, matrices of zero width or height are representable, but these functions don’t handle the possibility (e.g. `matrixDimension` calls `head` on a possibly-empty list); you can avoid this using `Data.List.NonEmpty` or `Data.Array` as your backing type, the latter of which is also more efficient